# Retrieving exact tag value from aws ec2 instances

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, grep, tags

I'm using the below command to get the AWS EC2 instance tag value for the tag name called 'Name', but the problem is that I also have a tag called 'Cluster Name' so the code below outputs the tag values for both 'Name' and 'Cluster Name' tags.

How can I make it so that I only retrieve the tag value for 'Name' tag?

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --region us-east-1 --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=i-01159fca884xxxxxx" | grep -2 Name | grep Value | tr -d ' ' | cut -f2 -d: | tr -d '"' | tr -d ','
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on a Mac (quotation formatting might need to change for Windows):v

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=instance-id,Values=i-xxx --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value' --output text
```

Here's a very useful reference for understanding how to use `--query`: [JMESPath Tutorial](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)

Comment: This is giving me a return value of 'Name'. That is the name of the tag, but I wanted to get at the value of that tag..

Comment: Oops! Updated to use `Value`.